# can LIMIT and OFFSET help reduce time of execution in case of large tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to access very large tables in MySql from PHP,but the time of execution is very big (more than 10 minutes some times), I tried using limit and offset trying to reduce the time of execution,but they didn't help. I set limit to 1 so that once I find the row, it stops searching for more rows, and I used Offset so that the next time it's searching for a row, to start searching from the last row reached :

```
$offset1 = 0; 

for ($date = mktime($hour_i,$minute_i,0,$month_i,$day_i,$year_i); $date <= mktime($hour_f,$minute_f,0,$month_f,$day_f,$year_f); $date = mktime($hour,$minute+$time_step,0,$month,$day,$year)) 
{
$hour = date('H',$date);
$minute = date('i',$date);
$second = date('S', $date);
$day = date('d',$date);
$month = date('m',$date);
$year = date('Y',$date);
?>

<?php

$Ensoleillement_Query = mysql_query("SELECT Moyenne, @row := @row + 1 AS ROW FROM mesure_ensoleillement,(SELECT @row := 0) r WHERE IdMesure  IN(SELECT IdMesures FROM mesures WHERE IdPasserelle='".$PERSIL."' and  ColonneEnregistrement='IdEnsoleillement')
and hour(DateMesure)= ".$hour."
and minute(DateMesure) = ".$minute."
and year(DateMesure)= ".$year."
and month(DateMesure)= ".$month."
and day(DateMesure)= ".$day." LIMIT 1 OFFSET ".$offset1." ");

if (!$Ensoleillement_Query) {
    die('Query failure Query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

if(mysql_num_rows($Ensoleillement_Query) == 0)  die("There is no Data in the Database corresponding to that date or site");

$Ensoleillement[$i] = mysql_result($Ensoleillement_Query,0,0);
$offset1 = mysql_result($Ensoleillement_Query,0,1);
$offset1 = $offset1-1;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` affects the performance of *reading* the data. Let's use an example:

Someone gives you a newspaper and says *"read all of it then tell me what's on page three"*. Or he could say *"read just page three and tell me about it"*. The last one is how a limit works. You'll be done sooner because you're not trying to read things you don't end up needing.

Now imagine the person is across the room from you and he needs to walk over to you to hand you the newspaper. It's not going to matter how much of the newspaper you will read, walking over will take the same amount of time. `LIMIT` has no effect on this. To make the person walk faster (to complete the analogy) you can add indexes or optimize the query in other ways.

Comment: OK thanks,
but do you know how can I return the row number of the record selected in the initial table in MySQL?
cz there's no such thing as row_number() in MySql

Comment: There is no such thing as a row number. I'm not sure what you want to do with it but counting each row as you read it in PHP is trivial.

Comment: OK one more question, when I say LIMIT 1 OFFSET 100 WHERE ...  for example, does that mean that the query will go to the initial table where Im selecting records from, skip 100 rows and start looking for the record, once it finds it, it stops looking?